# In an "each" loop, the charts are appended to the div created in the last loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have been using each loop to create a google bar chart and sankey chart in each loop per div. The `BLOQUES` array has three elements. I iterate through them, and in each loop, I create a div, to generate and place a bar chart and sankey chart. However, for some reason, all sankey charts are appended to the third div (`BLQ3_MAIN`, the div created in the last loop). Below is my code:

```
function drawBarChart() {           
    $.each(BLOQUES , function(index, bloque){
        $bloque = $("<div id='" + bloque + "_MAIN'></div>");

        $("#BLOQUES").append($bloque);

        pages = $.grep(myArray, function(n, i) {return n.BLOQUE === bloque;});

        $.each(pages, function(index, page){                
            $page = $("<div style='class='" + page.PAGE_SHORT + "'></div>");
            $bloque.append($page);

            //THE CODE FOR ADDING BARCHART GOES HERE
            //AND IT WORKS FINE         
        });

        //##################################################
        //DRAW SANKEY ACROSS PAGES FOR EACH BLOQUE

        $.get('pw_' + bloque +  '_COLL.csv', function(mydata){
            var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(mydata, {onParseValue:$.csv.hooks.castToScalar});                
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

            //SOME OTHER CODE SKIPPED

            $sankey_holder = $('<div id="' + bloque + '_sankey"></div>');               
            $bloque.append($sankey_holder);                 

            var chart_sankey = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById(bloque + '_sankey'));
            chart_sankey.draw(data, options);           
        });     
    });
}
```

Regarding these two lines:

```
$sankey_holder = $('<div id="' + bloque + '_sankey"></div>');               
$bloque.append($sankey_holder);
```

`bloque` carries the expected value in each iteration, but `$bloque` is always the div created in the third loop (i.e., `BLQ3_MAIN`). Probably I am missing some logic regarding how this code should work.

When I try this instead:

```
var chart_sankey = new google.visualization.Sankey($sankey_holder));
```

I receive the `Container is not defined` error.

Any ideas and suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the result of making an asynchronous call within a loop

`$.get` is asynchronous,
which means the loop doesn't wait for `$.get` to finish before going to the next index

when `$.get` finally finishes and fires the callback with `mydata`,
`bloque` is equal to the last value, because the loop has finished

to lock the value of `bloque`,
call a separate function with `bloque` as the argument
this will prevent the reference to the last value,
when `$.get` finishes

---

see following snippet...

```
function drawBarChart() {
    $.each(BLOQUES , function(index, bloque){
        $bloque = $("<div id='" + bloque + "_MAIN'></div>");

        $("#BLOQUES").append($bloque);

        pages = $.grep(myArray, function(n, i) {return n.BLOQUE === bloque;});

        $.each(pages, function(index, page){
            $page = $("<div style='class='" + page.PAGE_SHORT + "'></div>");
            $bloque.append($page);

            //THE CODE FOR ADDING BARCHART GOES HERE
            //AND IT WORKS FINE
        });

        //##################################################
        //DRAW SANKEY ACROSS PAGES FOR EACH BLOQUE

        drawSankey(bloque);
    });
}

function drawSankey(bloque) {
    $.get('pw_' + bloque +  '_COLL.csv', function(mydata){
        var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(mydata, {onParseValue:$.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

        //SOME OTHER CODE SKIPPED

        $sankey_holder = $('<div id="' + bloque + '_sankey"></div>');
        $bloque.append($sankey_holder);

        var chart_sankey = new google.visualization.Sankey($sankey_holder[0]);
        chart_sankey.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

---

note: the jquery reference to `$sankey_holder` is an array
use the first element to create the chart

```
$sankey_holder[0]
```

e.g.

```
var chart_sankey = new google.visualization.Sankey($sankey_holder[0]);
```

---

also, may need to pass `$bloque` as well, depending on where it is defined

```
drawSankey($bloque, bloque);

...

function drawSankey($bloque, bloque) {
```